# Passing value to JS function through URL on window load

Tags: javascript, url, variables, get, onload

my page http://www.dinomuhic.com/2010/index.php loads the Showreel at the start of the page using an onLoad call in body like this:

```
<body onLoad="sndReq('96')">
```

96 is the ID of the showreel in the SQL Library.
The JS function "sndReq" is an AJAX call using JQuery which opens the requested item and displays it in the main window.

Now my question: What if I want to send a link to a client which opens a specific item directly so he does not have to navigate through the site?

Something like http://www.dinomuhic.com/2010/index.php?sndReq=234 (which of course doesn't work now and just opens the showreel, probably because the onLoad in the body tag overrides it)

How can I implement this? I want to be able to open specific items by URL but if nothing is passed through the URL it should always open item 96.

Thank you in advance. I'm sure its pretty easy I just can't see it.

Cletus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to parse the query string.  I find the easiest way to deal with the query string is to do the following.  First, you need to extract the query string from the URL:

```
var queryStr = window.location.search; // will give you ?sndReq=234
```

Then, you can strip out the `?` and split each query string parameter into an array:

```
var paramPairs = queryStr.substr(1).split('&');
```

Now you can build a hash table object of the name/value pairs making up the query string:

```
var params = {};
for (var i = 0; i < paramPairs.length; i++) {
    var parts = paramPairs[i].split('=');
    params[parts[0]] = parts[1];
}
```

In your `onload`, you can now use the parameter thusly:

```
sndReq(params.sndReq);
```

Make sure that the code is run within a script in the `head` of your document so that it's computed before the `onload` is executed.

Comment: what if the string contains hash #?

Comment: That will be in `window.location.hash`, not included in `window.location.search`.

Comment: Thanks, I combined yours and keeganwatkins solution into one that fits me perfect! Again thank you both very much!

Comment: in case someone wants to know: `var queryStr = window.location.search;
var paramPairs = queryStr.substr(1).split('=');
var query = paramPairs[1];

    if ( !query ) {
        query = '96';
    }

sndReq(query);`

Answer (score 4):

if you are using jQuery, why not use the DOM-ready handler instead of `onload` ? on that note, if it's just an ajax request, you don't even need to wait for DOM-ready. if you parse the query, you should be able to pass that in to your existing function.

```
// Wait for DOM-ready, may not be needed if you are just
// making a request, up to you to decide :)
$(function() {
    // window.location.search represents the query string for
    // current URL, including the leading '?', so strip it off.
    var query = window.location.search.replace(/^\?/, "");

    // If there is no query, default to '96'
    if ( !query ) {
        query = '96';
    }

    // Call existing function, passing the query value
    sndReq( query );
});
```

hope that helps! cheers.

Comment: Hey thanks, I understood how to replace my onLoad in the body tag with the Query call. But the rest doesnt work. Leaves me with a page where no item is being shown. Where do I have to put the whole function? Or is it enough to place everything whats in our function into my window.ready function?

Comment: you should be able to place that function in the `head` tag, or add the code from the function into another DOM-ready handler (if you already have one). if you do `console.log(query)` before calling `sndReq` does it have the value you expect?

Comment: I put it into the window.ready function like this `var queryStr = window.location.search;
var paramPairs = queryStr.substr(1).split('=');
var query = paramPairs[1];

    if ( !query ) {
        query = '96';
    }

sndReq(query);` and it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegExp to accomplish this, read the url parameters and pass them to ajax.

this simple script will read the current url and pass through regex to filter for paramters you specify.

- EG:  ThisReq = gip('sndReq'); pulls sndReq and value from the url.

---

```
<script language="javascript">
    function gip(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
        if (results == null)
            sndReq('96');
         else
            return results[1];
    }
    // parameter pulled from url.
    ThisReq = gip('sndReq');
    // executes function sndReq();
    sndReq(''+ThisReq+'');
</script>
```

---

Comment: `window.location.search` has this value already (it's more reliable than manual parsing). also, why add to extra globals (`gip` and `ThisReq`) if they are not needed?

Comment: those globals i added in my case because i have more than 9 parameters to filter, all being dynamic. I guess i just did not know a better way.

`    pfWidth = gup('width');
    pfHeight = gup('height');
    pfThumbs = gup('Thumbs');
    pfThumbSize = gup('ThumbSize');
    pftheURL = gup('theURL');
    pfAppID = gup('AppID');
    pftheID = gup('theID');
    pfDefault = gup('SetDefault');
    pfAlbum = gup('DefaultAlbum');`