# Call function in browser console after clicked hyperlink in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have such situation. I have to call function in browser console after user clicked a hyperlink in Excel. One of function's argument is based on row's data, so it's kinda dynamically generated.

Is this possible within Excel environment?

If anything is unclear, let me know.

Thanks guys.

**EDIT**: I have thought already about using batch file, to convert hole excel file to html or use Python script, but non of this is simple. Problem is that I'm not a VBA guy, so I'm asking SO community to suggest if that kind of thing is even possible in Excel(VBA).

Comment: Kindly show us your effort prior to asking the question here.

Comment: I have thought already about using batch file, to convert hole excel file to html or use Python script, but non of this is simple. Problem is that I'm not a VBA guy, so I'm asking SO community to suggest if that kind of thing is even possible in Excel(VBA).

Comment: Add it to the question.

Comment: Use the `HYPERLINK` function to generate links, and include the relevant row's data in the generated URL as a bunch of GET parameters. Read them from javascript on the web side.

Comment: Thanks. It's true. I forgot about parameters in url, very useful. Anyways, I still have to execute js code (to get parameters and finally run a function) after webpage is loaded. You know anything that could help me achive that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7770887/11683